# Multidimensional '3D' Matrix in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What will be the syntax of creating a 3D matrix in Kotlin. It's Java equivalent is as follows:

```
public static final int[][][] data = {{{0,0},{0}},{{0,1},{0}},{{1,0},{0}},{{1,1},{1}}};
```

Thanks

Edit:
Also how can I print the Kotlin code using the simple println?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin currently does not support array literals.

You can use a combination of `arrayOf()` and `intArrayOf()`:

```
val data = arrayOf(
  arrayOf(intArrayOf(0, 0), intArrayOf(0)),
  arrayOf(intArrayOf(0, 1), intArrayOf(0)),
  arrayOf(intArrayOf(1, 0), intArrayOf(0)),
  arrayOf(intArrayOf(1, 1), intArrayOf(1))
)
```

You can cut down a little bit on the verbosity using import aliasing if needed:

```
import kotlin.arrayOf as arr
import kotlin.intArrayOf as iarr

val data = arr(
  arr(iarr(0, 0), iarr(0)),
  arr(iarr(0, 1), iarr(0)),
  arr(iarr(1, 0), iarr(0)),
  arr(iarr(1, 1), iarr(1))
)
```

Also note that you can auto-convert Java code to Kotlin

- in IntelliJ IDEA: copy Java code into a Kotlin file, a confirmation prompt will open.
- online: using http://try.kotlinlang.org.

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell me how can we print it using a simple for loop?

Comment: Depends on how you want to print it, using `.forEach` would be one way. You seem to be new to Kotlin, so you may want to consult [the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html) to learn at your own pace.

Comment: Okay sure. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Access the elements as usual `data[i][j][k]`

Answer (score 3):

When working with arrays in most languages I find it nice to create a helper class, rather than working directly with an `int[][][]` type. This way you can ensure certain invariants hold (such as all rows having the same length), and ensure better data locality. It can also let you efficiently implement certain operations such as slicing, sub-matrices,  transpose etc.

My usual set of classes would look something like this for 3D. (though I'd probably template on the stored type, rather than hard code it for `Int`)
Its pretty incomplete, but the main at the end shows how many of the functions work.

But to show how you can create a 3D array from values you can do

```
val V = /* .. as in  mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu's answer */
val M = Matrix3D(NX,NY,NZ).transform( { v, ix, iy, iz -> V[ix][iy][iz] } )
```

Further examples are

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  // Create an empty matrix
  val v = Matrix3D(4,4,2);

  // We can access elements via [a,b,c] or [a][b][c]
  v[0,1,1] = 7;
  print(v)
  println("v[0,1,1]=" + v[0,1,1])
  println("v[0][1][1]=" + v[0][1][1])

  println("-----")
  // Make the matrix a little more interesting
  v.transform({ w,ix,iy,iz -> ix+iy+iz})
  print(v)

  println("-----")  
  // Transform just the slice with ix=2
  // Slices are fast, as they copy no elements. 
  // but if you change them you change the original

  v[2].transform({w,iy,iz -> w+3})
  print(v)

  // If you dont want to change the original you can always
  // create an independent copy
  print(v[2].bake().transform({w,iy,iz -> w-3}))

  println("-----")
  // W is the slice of v with ix=0
  // Can easily extend the slicing options to allow slicing along 
  // any axis - I'd like to add v[_,1,_] to mean the slice with iy=1
  //  but I've not got to that yet.
  val W = v[0]
  print("W=\n")
  print(v[0])
  print("W^T=\n")

  // Fast transpose, no elements are copied.
  val WT=v[0].transpose()
  print(WT)

  // Changing the transpose slice writes back into the original
  WT[1,1]=5
  print(V)
}

fun print(M:Matrix3D) {
   for(iz in 0..(M.nz-1)) {
        for(iy in 0..(M.ny-1)) {
            for(ix in 0..(M.nx-1)){
                 print("%d ".format(M[ix,iy,iz]))
            }
            print("\n")
        }
       print("\n")
    } 
}

fun print(M:Matrix2D) {
    for(iy in 0..(M.ny-1)) {
        for(ix in 0..(M.nx-1)){
             print("%d ".format(M[ix,iy]))
        }
        print("\n")
    }
}
```

The library code looks like this:

```
class Matrix1D(
    val v:Array<Int>, 
    val nx:Int,
    val offset:Int,
    val xstride:Int) {
      // TODO: Check that the nx,offset,strides etc are valid

    constructor(nx:Int) : this(Array(nx,{i->0}), nx, 0, 1) {

    }

    fun offsetof(ix:Int):Int {
        return offset + ix*xstride
    }

    operator fun get(ix:Int): Int {
      return v[offsetof(ix)]
    }

    operator fun set(ix:Int, v:Int) {
      this.v[offsetof(ix)] = v
    }

    fun reverse() : Matrix1D {
        return Matrix1D(v, nx, offsetof(nx-1), -xstride)
    }

    fun submatrix(startx:Int, newNX:Int) : Matrix1D {
        return Matrix1D(v,newNX,offsetof(startx), xstride)
    }

    fun transform(body: (Int, Int) -> Int ) {
        for(ix in 0..(nx-1)){
            this[ix] = body(this[ix], ix)
        }
    } 

    fun bake() : Matrix1D {
        val rv = Matrix1D(nx);
        for(ix in 0..(nx-1)) {
            rv[ix] = this[ix]
        }
        return rv
    }
}

class Matrix2D(
    val v:Array<Int>, 
    val nx:Int, val ny:Int,
    val offset:Int,
    val xstride:Int, val ystride:Int) {
      // TODO: Check that the nx,ny,offset,strides etc are valid

    constructor(nx:Int, ny:Int) : this(Array(nx*ny,{i->0}), nx, ny, 0, 1, nx ) {

    }

    fun offsetof(ix:Int,iy:Int): Int {
        return offset + ix*xstride + iy*ystride
    }

    operator fun get(ix:Int,iy:Int): Int {
      return v[offsetof(ix,iy)]
    }

    operator fun set(ix:Int,iy:Int,v:Int) {
      this.v[offsetof(ix,iy)] = v
    }

    operator fun get(ix:Int): Matrix1D {
        return Matrix1D(v, ny, offsetof(ix,0), ystride)
    }

    fun transpose(): Matrix2D {
        return Matrix2D(v,ny,nx,offset,ystride,xstride)
    }

    fun submatrix(startx:Int, starty:Int, newNX:Int, newNY:Int) : Matrix2D {
        return Matrix2D(v,newNX,newNY,offsetof(startx,starty), xstride, ystride)
    }

    fun transform(body: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int ) {
        for(iy in 0..(ny-1)) {
            for(ix in 0..(nx-1)){
                 this[ix,iy] = body(this[ix,iy], ix,iy)
            }
        }
    } 

    fun bake() : Matrix2D {
        val rv = Matrix2D(nx,ny);
        for(ix in 0..(nx-1)) {
            for(iy in 0..(ny-1)) {
                    rv[ix,iy] = this[ix,iy]
            }
        }
        return rv
    }
}

class Matrix3D(
    val v:Array<Int>, 
    val nx:Int, val ny:Int, val nz:Int, 
    val offset:Int,
    val xstride:Int, val ystride:Int, val zstride:Int) {
      // TODO: Check that the nx,ny,nz,offset,strides etc are valid

    constructor(nx:Int, ny:Int, nz:Int) : this(Array(nx*ny*nz,{i->0}), nx, ny, nz, 0, 1, nx, nx*ny ) {

    }
    operator fun get(ix:Int,iy:Int,iz:Int): Int {
      return v[offset + ix*xstride + iy*ystride + iz*zstride]
    }

    operator fun set(ix:Int,iy:Int,iz:Int, v:Int) {
      this.v[offset + ix*xstride + iy*ystride + iz*zstride] = v
    }

    operator fun get(ix:Int): Matrix2D {
        return Matrix2D(v, ny, nz, offset + ix*xstride, ystride, zstride )
    }

    fun transform(body: (Int, Int, Int, Int) -> Int ) {
       for(iz in 0..(nz-1)) {
        for(iy in 0..(ny-1)) {
            for(ix in 0..(nx-1)){
                 this[ix,iy,iz] = body(this[ix,iy,iz], ix,iy,iz)
            }
        }
    } 
}

    fun bake() : Matrix3D {
        val rv = Matrix3D(nx,ny,nz);
        for(ix in 0..(nx-1)) {
            for(iy in 0..(ny-1)) {
                for(iz in 0..(nz-1)){
                    rv[ix,iy,iz] = this[ix,iy,iz]
                }
            }
        }
        return rv
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Multik**
Multik Multidimensional array library for Kotlin.

Syntax for creating 3D array

```
mk.d3array(2, 2, 3) { it * it }
//output
/*[[[0, 1, 4],
[9, 16, 25]],

[[1, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1]]]
*/
```

**Note**:Multik supports up to 4 dimensions

The Multik project’s [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Kotlin/multik)
For more info check [Jetbrain blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/02/multik-multidimensional-arrays-in-kotlin/)